# Updating result for self created operations

Tags: java, operation, cumulocity

I'm pretty new to working with cumulocity and I'm trying to change the result for self created operations.
For Shell operations this solution works [setting c8y_Command result String from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422626/setting-c8y-command-result-string-from-java). But for other operations it doesn't. The Operation would look something like this:

```
"status": "PENDING",
"description": "description text",
"c8y_GetData": {
    "result": "",
    "name": "data name",
    "dataType": "c8y_data",
    "dataID": "234324"
}
```

The in the device view the result entry in the detail tab for the operation is always empty. I tried to put the result almost anywhere to let it show up on the page.
Maybe one of you knows where and with what name to up it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Lee, I am not sure if I understand the question fully. You want your "c8y_GetData.result" to be shown as "Result" in the "Control" tab in device management? I think currently, it's hard-coded to show c8y_Command.result in the user interface.

Comment: Yes that was my intention. But it's good to know that is only available for c8y_Command. Thanks for the answer.